# Android - Recycleview Inside Scrollview

Tags: android, layout, android-recyclerview, android-scrollview

I am building a social app and have an activity for viewing user's profiles (like Instagram).

**I basically want to be able to scroll normally and naturally from the ScrollView to the RecyclerView and viceversa.**
So for example, if the user does a strong swipe from the bottom of the RecyclerView I want it to take him up to the top of the ScrollView . I was thinking of the following solution (but don't really know how to do it): make the RecyclerView's height "expanded" so it would contain all the items but with no scrollbar, so that the ScrollView can do it's a natural thing.

My layout looks like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

   <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <!-- FIRST REGION THIS IS SET PRGRAMATICALLY TO TAKE UP WHOLE SCREEN-->

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

              <ImageView> <Textview> <Bla> <Bla>

         </RelativeLayout>

   <!-- SECOND REGION ALSO SET TO TAKE UP ALL SCREEN PROGRAMATICALLY-->

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
             />

        </RelativeLayout>

   </LinearLayout>

   </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Screenshots: 
[First Region](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fs0W0.png)
[Second Region](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGSOG.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this `mRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);`